# What's different between df.iloc[0]['column_A'] vs df['column_A'][0]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I get values by the following approaches, I have the same result.

```
df.iloc[0]['column_A'][:100]

df['column_A'][0][:100]
```

Also, when I using `type`, they are returned with value `str`.

What's different?

Comment: Both approaches are really-really bad when it comes to readability. Pandas docs recommend using `loc` except special cases so it's better to write `df.loc[0, 'column_A'][:100]`.

Comment: @NotAName what's your evidence to desribe that both are bad? loc and iloc are just different methods to get values based on labels and indices.

Comment: @HSL Pandas users generally have a negative view of chain indexing.(indexing like you) There are various reasons for this, including efficiency issues, code readability and consistency concerns, and the creation of copies. Above comment is a general-level advice against using chain indexing. While I agree that it is generally better to avoid it, I do not think it should be banned.

Comment: @Pandas Kim Thanks to answering the question, then where can I refer to this when encountering similar problems? Can you recommend some places for me to get deep understanding of this mechanism?

Comment: Check these out: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/cookbook.html

Comment: @NotAName Thanks, there are things which are valuable to try.